# How to split the time series into two based on an anchor date (and week count) in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

Here is the time series df `df_curr`, with datetime as index.

```
df_curr.head()
                ZONE  REF_WEEK  N_PTS  
WEEK_START                                                                                                                                                     
2018-03-04  Province         1  14196     
2018-03-11  Province         2  14683     
2018-03-18  Province         3  14992     
2018-03-25  Province         4  14168     
2018-04-01  Province         5  14232     

df_curr.tail()
                ZONE  REF_WEEK  N_PTS    
WEEK_START                                                                                                                                             
2020-09-27  Province       135  14547     
2020-10-04  Province       136  14582    
2020-10-11  Province       137  14532     
2020-10-18  Province       138  14555     
2020-10-25  Province       139  14561
```

I want to generate two smaller time series `df_during` and `df_pre`. The more recent time series will be from `2020-03-01` to a total of 35 weeks after (inclusive). The earlier time series will be 35 weeks before `2020-03-01`. The following code works, but I wonder if there are better solutions (that I can combine the date comparison and 35 weeks counting in one line).

```
start_week = '2020-03-01'
week_n = 35
df_curr = df_curr.sort_index()
df_during = df_curr[df_curr.index >= startweek]
df_during = df_during[:week_n]

df_pre = df_curr[df_curr.index < startweek]
df_pre = df_pre[-week_n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
df_pre, df_during = df.groupby((df_curr.index - df_curr.index.min()).days/7 >= 35)
```